# A saying for being aligned and showing externally that you are on the same page?

Tags: idiom-requests

Something like 'putting up the same front'? Putting on the same face?

Basically, you are in negotiations and first you come to agreement internally and want to show that to the external parties in the negotiations.

Comment: It’s “on the same page”...

Comment: ...or "putting up" or "showing" "a common front".

Comment: If you want something more prosaic, "showing solidarity."